# Map with an accumulator in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to map over a sequence in order but want to carry an accumulator value forward, like in a reduce.

Example use case: Take a vector and return a running total, each value multiplied by two.

```
(defn map-with-accumulator
  "Map over input but with an accumulator. func accepts [value accumulator] and returns [new-value new-accumulator]."
  [func accumulator collection]
  (if (empty? collection)
    nil
    (let [[this-value new-accumulator] (func (first collection) accumulator)]
      (cons this-value (map-with-accumulator func new-accumulator (rest collection))))))

(defn double-running-sum
  [value accumulator]
  [(* 2 (+ value accumulator)) (+ value accumulator)])
```

Which gives

```
(prn (pr-str (map-with-accumulator double-running-sum 0 [1 2 3 4 5])))

>>> (2 6 12 20 30)
```

Another example to illustrate the generality, print running sum as stars and the original number. A slightly convoluted example, but demonstrates that I need to keep the running accumulator in the map function:

```
(defn stars [n] (apply str (take n (repeat \*))))

(defn stars-sum [value accumulator]
  [[(stars (+ value accumulator)) value] (+ value accumulator)])

(prn (pr-str (map-with-accumulator stars-sum 0 [1 2 3 4 5])))
>>> (["*" 1] ["***" 2] ["******" 3] ["**********" 4] ["***************" 5])
```

This works fine, but I would expect this to be a common pattern, and for some kind of `map-with-accumulator` to exist in `core`. Does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into `reductions`. For this specific case:

```
(reductions #(+ % (* 2 %2)) 2 (range 2 6))
```

produces

(2 6 12 20 30)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that captures the generality of my question though (I had to illustrate it but perhaps the illustration didn't exhibit the generality adequately). I've added another example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting, I wanted to be sure that this covered my use case. It does, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**The general solution**

The common pattern of a mapping that can depend on both an item and the accumulating sum of a sequence is captured by the function

```
(defn map-sigma [f s] (map f s (sigma s)))
```

where

```
(def sigma (partial reductions +))
```

... returns the sequence of accumulating sums of a sequence:

```
(sigma (repeat 12 1))
; (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)

(sigma [1 2 3 4 5])
; (1 3 6 10 15)
```

In the definition of `map-sigma`, `f` is a function of two arguments, the item followed by the accumulator.

**The examples**

In these terms, the first example can be expressed

```
(map-sigma (fn [_ x] (* 2 x)) [1 2 3 4 5])
; (2 6 12 20 30)
```

In this case, the mapping function ignores the item and depends only on the accumulator.

The second can be expressed

```
(map-sigma #(vector (stars %2) %1) [1 2 3 4 5])
; (["*" 1] ["***" 2] ["******" 3] ["**********" 4] ["***************" 5])
```

... where the mapping function depends on both the item and the accumulator.

There is no standard function like `map-sigma`.

**General conclusions**

- Just because a pattern of computation is common does not imply that
  it merits or requires its own standard function.
- Lazy sequences and the sequence library are powerful enough to tease
  apart many problems into clear function compositions.

---

Rewritten to be specific to the question posed.

---

Edited to accommodate the changed second example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this answers the examples but not the actual question (a map where the running accumulator is available). I've edited the stars to demonstrate this (note I haven't changed the question or the function I'm asking about!).

Comment: @Joe - adapted to make the running accumulator available to any mapping.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer + effort. I accepted the other because he was first, sorry. I'd double-upvote if I could!

Comment: @Joe No problem. I had to get it right for myself. The insight is the parameterisation: obvious once seen, but harder to capture. The thing about functional programming is that the perfect expression of the question *is* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reductions is the way to go as Diego mentioned however to your specific problem the following works

```
(map #(* % (inc %)) [1 2 3 4 5])
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the "how do I calculate this sequence of numbers" not "does this higher-order function exist?". I suppose that's my fault for providing an example. Anyway, I've added another one to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you could use `reductions`:

```
(defn map-with-accumulator [f init-value collection]
  (map first (reductions (fn [[_ accumulator] next-elem]
                           (f next-elem accumulator))
                         (f (first collection) init-value)
                         (rest collection))))

=> (map-with-accumulator double-running-sum 0 [1 2 3 4 5])
(2 6 12 20 30)

=> (map-with-accumulator stars-sum 0 [1 2 3 4 5])
("*" "***" "******" "**********" "***************")
```

It's only in case you want to keep the original requirements. Otherwise I'd prefer to decompose `f` into two separate functions and use Thumbnail's approach.